# Unable to get correct EndTime for the next Stage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get how long an activity has been "InProgress" based on the history data i have. Each history record contains StartTime and the "Stage" of an activity.
Stages flow like this:

```
Ready
InProgress
Completed
```

Also there is a stage named "OnHold" which puts an activity on Hold. While calculating how long an activity has been "InProgress", i need to subtract the amount of time it was "OnHold".

In the given example you will see Activity named "MA50665" went "InProgress" at "2014-07-17 13:08:04.013" and then was put on hold at "2014-07-17 13:12:14.473" which is roughly about 4 minutes. Then it went "InProgress" again at "2014-07-17 13:22:45.503" and was completed at around "2014-07-17 13:33:38.513" which is roughly around 11 minutes. Which means MA50665 was InProgress for about 11+4=15 minutes.

I have the query which is getting me close to what i am looking for. It gives me two records for "MA50665" which i am expecting but the **EndTime for both the records comes to "2014-07-17 13:33:38.513" which is incorrect.**

For start time "2014-07-17 13:08:04.013", EndTime should have been "2014-07-17 13:12:14.473" because that is when the "InProgress" stage ends. For the second row, StartTime and EndTime are correct.

**How do i say in the query that Get the End Time for the stage from the next history row of that activity?** I cannot hard code "+1" in the join .

Here is the SQLFiddle for the Table schema and query:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37ef3/4

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm seeing a duplicate row in your example that you say works but has the "+1" in it.  Records 5 & 6, seem to be the same but have different end times.  Assuming that you are correct here is a fix for the query.

```
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY T1.Seqid, T1.Historyid)Rnumber, 
     T1.Srid, 
     T1.Activityid, 
     T1.Seqid, 
     T1.Currentactstatus, 
     T1.Previousactstatus, 
     T1.Timechanged Statusstarttime, 
     Endtimehist.Timechanged Statusendtime
 FROM T1
     LEFT JOIN T1 Endtimehist ON T1.Srid = Endtimehist.Srid
                        AND T1.Activityid = Endtimehist.Activityid
                        AND T1.Currentactstatus = Endtimehist.Previousactstatus
WHERE T1.SRId = 'SR50660'
  AND T1.Currentactstatus = 'InProgress'
   AND T1.Previousactstatus = 'Ready'
  AND T1.Historyid < Endtimehist.Historyid --This works but i cannot hard code +1 here as history ids may appear in the random incrementing order
ORDER BY T1.SRId DESC, T1.SeqId, T1.HistoryId
```